# React Native Case Statement, If statement or Conditional Rendering Based on Value

Tags: javascript, react-native, if-statement

I'm trying to create rank levels based on the users account XP which I get from firestore. So if the user has 3000XP he'll be level 3 for example.

I assume the best case for this would be to build a long if statement with all the possible values for example:

```
if (CurrentAccountXP == '1000') {
return 1
} else if (CurrentAccountXP == '2000') {
return 2
}
```

etc etc

**Attempted solution based on Tarik's response**

```
const CurrentAccountXP = userData.accountXP;

const levels = [
0, 1250, 2500, 3750, 5000, 6250, 7500, 8750, 10000, 11250, 12500, 13750,
15000, 16250, 17500, 18750, 20000, 21250, 22500, 23750, 25000, 26250, 27500,
28750, 30000, 31250, 32500, 33750, 35000, 36250, 37500, 38750, 40000, 41250,
42500, 43750, 45000, 46250, 47500, 48750, 50000, 51250, 52500, 53750, 55000,
56250, 57500, 58750, 60000, 61250, 62500, 63750, 65000, 66250, 67500, 68750,
70000, 71250, 72500, 73750, 75000,
];

let level = 0;
const experience = CurrentAccountXP;

levels.forEach((v, i) => {
if (experience >= v) {
  level = i + 1;
}
console.log(level);
});
```

**Code that pulls in current accounts experience points**

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
const user = auth.currentUser;

const GetUserData = async () => {
const response = firestore.collection("users").doc(user.uid);
const observer = response.onSnapshot(
  (docSnapshot) => {
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      setUserData(docSnapshot.data());
      //console.log("User Data Fetched: ", userData);
    }
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
  }
);
const unsub = firestore.collection("users").onSnapshot(() => {});
  return () => unsub;
};

useEffect(() => {
  GetUserData();
}, []);
```

Comment: If it’s linear you could divide the XP thru 1000. What do you do if a user has 2400XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to save the XP as numbers. Then your if statemtn could be like:

```js
if (CurrentAccountXP >= 1000 && < 2000) {
return 1
} else if (CurrentAccountXP >= 2000 && < 3000) {
return 2
}
```

That way you capture also the XP if they are in between. If you create an array of levels and the min and max XPs you could generalize it with "smarter" function that loops trough the levels and checks the XP to get the correct level.

Comment: Thanks @Tarik. I've tried making an array of xp values which then based on the account's current xp will give it the level from the array index. My only concern now it seems that this being called multiple times looking at the console log. Is this perhaps because of my GetUserData Function? I've edited my question to showcase

Comment: Can you pls post that under a new question to not complicate this here for SO.